# How to make this complex layout in JSF?

Tags: css, jsf, templates, user-interface, primefaces

i am trying to make my general layout in primefaces, with 5 different regions (top, left, center, right, bottom).

[image]

I already had try a full layout page but in the center container i need a tabview with scroll bar only in the child element and not at center container. If my implement this image layout with full layout page, the scoll bar will be present on the center container. How i can do this?

I dont want to do this with divs. I only want use primefaces components.

thanks for all your help!

Comment: You can use template. In template you can define 3 section header, body, footer like `<ui:insert name="header">
 <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/template/header.xhtml" />
</ui:insert>
<ui:insert name="body" /> <ui:insert name="footer">
 <ui:include src="/WEB-INF/template/footer.xhtml" />
</ui:insert>` In body define 3 parts: left, center, right.

Comment: thanks.. i make this with divs.